# App not navigating to second view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The code I am using

```
  NSLog(@"before Navigate to second activity");
    Signature *temp = [[Signature alloc]initWithNibName:@"Signature" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];

     NSLog(@"after Navigate to second activity");
```

On console,both the log statements are getting printed, but my app is not navigating me to the next View.Please correct me.

Comment: Check that `self.navigationController` is not `nil`.

Comment: you are correct. The self.navigationController is null.

Comment: @onkar this is null bcoz you not assign rootviewcontroller with navigation controller so see my code and assign navigation controller try with your controller just change name

Comment: Well, do you have a navigation controller at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using a `UINavigationController` on your app you can not call `pushViewController`, use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead:

```
[self presentViewController:temp animated:YES completion:nil];
```

for more information check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a)

Comment: int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
in my main file at this line I am getting SIGABRT

Comment: from which point on your application are you calling this method?, which kind of class is ``self``?, which is the super class of ``self``?

Comment: Its superclass is UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

i think your application is not with navigationController so in AppDelegate.m file assign rootViewController like this..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    RootViewController *viewController1 = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController   *navviewController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    self.window.rootViewController = navviewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

after that check its working..

Comment: If you're not using ARC you're leaking navviewController.

Comment: here in ARC autorelese and relese (Autocorrection) not work so if we use navigationacontroller with autorelese then here our app crashed mate..

Comment: So use an ivar, assign a new instance of navcontroller to your ivar and after release it. Then you can release and nil your self.navcontroller ivar in the dealloc.

Comment: instead of this if you not use concept of autorelese and relese in the application then not need any other functionality mate..

Answer (score 0):

The log messages would show anyway, so no surprise there. Add a callback to the delegate for that navigation controller (you must first set a delegate of course) for

```
navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:
```

There you can make sure that the viewController passed (make sure Signature is a ViewController instance).

Answer (score 0):

CreditsViewController *viewController = [[CreditsViewController alloc] init];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

[viewController release];

you can try with above code